# IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class does not implement the requested interface ma.glasnost.orika.Mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, orika

I'm having an issue starting my web app (spring boot + jersey) after adding orika mapper :

I have a maven dependency that contains some converters (my web app pom):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>c.s.r</groupId>
    <artifactId>v-c</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The v-c jar contains a `spring-devtools.properties` properties file in the src/main/resources/META-INF directory

```
restart.include.orika=/orika-core.*\.jar
```

And Orika dependency is declared in the v-c pom :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
    <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And in the v-c project I have a set of converters (within the `c.s.r.commun.converter` package) that all extend `ma.glasnost.orika.CustomMapper<A, B>` and override `public void mapAtoB(final A a, final B b, final MappingContext context)`

Finally, in my web app I'm declaring a configuration class :

```java
import c.s.r.commun.converter.AentityBdtoConverter;

@Configuration
public class OrikaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MapperFacade mapperOrika() {
        final MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        // adding all of my converters from v-c the same way as below 
        mapperFactory.classMap(A.class, B.class)
                .customize(new AentityBdtoConverter()).register();
        return mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }
}
```

The cause error is :

```
Error creating bean with name 'mapperOrika' defined in class path resource [c/s/r/config/OrikaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade]: Factory method 'mapperOrika' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class c.s.r.commun.converter.AentityBdtoConverter does not implement the requested interface ma.glasnost.orika.Mapper
```

Comment: Maybe its something as obvious as your webapp does not include the v-c project in a version where you attached the orika mappers?

Comment: @Nadir It's not, my web app references the right version of the v-c project/pom.